# Toast in OnPostExecute() once the fragment changes

Tags: android

**I have two fragments in my Activity : Fragment_A and Fragment_B.**

In Fragment A, I created an AsyncTask (when the user "swipeRefreshes" the screen). In the `onPostExecute()` of this task, I want to display a Toast :

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeRequestTask() {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TO_DISPLAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        //Some stuff
    }
}
```

If the user changes from `Fragment_A` to `Fragment_B` before the AsyncTask finishes, I get a crash:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException:` Fragment Fragment_A not attached to a context.

I know how to avoid the crash (by adding the condition `isAdded())`, but I want my Toast to be displayed no matter which Fragment is displayed/alive on top of my Activity.

Comment: Instead of getting the activity inside the onPostExecute by calling getActivity(), just pass the activity or context in the constructor. This way, the asyncTask will already have everything it needs.

Comment: Not working neither. The context is lost once the fragment vanishes.
Just for information, the "private class MakeRequestTask" is declared inside Fragment_A.

Comment: check my answer and try it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1stly I would like to suggest you, please make your MakeRequestTask inner class as static as this can be a memory leak. 
For your question, You need to pass the context to the class like below:

```
    private static class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        private WeakReference<Context> weakReference;

        MakeRequestTask(Context context) {
            //Some stuff
            weakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Some stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Some stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
// swipe layout will not be shown if fragment is not visible or destroyed
            if (isFragmentVisible) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
// toast will be shown no matter what fragment is visible
            if (weakReference != null) {
                Context context = weakReference.get();
                if (context != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "TO_DISPLAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            if (isFragmentVisible) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            //Some stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
Declare a boolean in `Fragment_A`

```
private boolean isFragmentVisible=false;
```

In `Fragment_A` class

Make this boolean true in `onCreateView()` of this `Fragment_A`

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyourlayout, container, false);
    isFragmentVisible = true;
    return view;
}
```

And make this boolean false in `onDestroyView()` of this fragment A

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        isFragmentVisible = false;
    }
```

> Finally use it in Asyntask of `Fragment_A` like this

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeRequestTask() {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
// swipe layout will not be shown if fragment is not visible or destroyed
        if(isFragmentVisible){
              swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
// toast will be shown no matter what fragment is visible
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TO_DISPLAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
       if(isFragmentVisible){
              swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        //Some stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use and `interface` or an `EventBus` in the `onPostExecute` method, and show the `Toast` inside the activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        activityContractInterface.showToast()
        }
    }
```

And in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void showToast(){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TO_DISPLAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Or the EventBus approach:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShowToastEvent()) 
//just create an empty class, hope you know what EventBus is
            }
```

And in your activity:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.Main){
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TO_DISPLAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

[EventBusLibrary](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)